# Not able use the average aggregate in view table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have created a table VQ1 using following clause.

```
CREATE VIEW VQ1 as
SELECT productid, productname, TO_CHAR(unitprice,'$9,999.99') AS "unitprice"     
  FROM products
 WHERE unitprice > avg(unitprice) 
  WITH READ ONLY;
```

I am getting an error that I can not use the aggregate function `AVG()` to find the average.

So how can I find `AVG()` for a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this mate:

```
CREATE VIEW VQ1 AS
SELECT
    productid,
    productname,
    TO_CHAR(unitprice, '$9,999.99') 'unitprice'
FROM
    products
GROUP BY
    productid
HAVING
    unitprice > AVG(unitprice);
```

Comment: The unitprice I am referring to is not the quoted one, come to think of it averaging a non numeric field for comparison. Edited then, @DavidFaber

Comment: Tag was changed, it has 'mysql' before that's why I've tried to answer it. Well, just forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `avg` is an aggregate function, it cannot be used in the select unless the other fields are specified in the `group by` clause.

```
create view VQ1 as
select productid, productname, 
TO_CHAR(unitprice,'$9,999.99') as "unitprice" 
from products,
(select avg(unitprice) as avgprice from products)
where unitprice > avgprice
with read only;
```

Comment: AFAIK, subqueries are not usable in creating a View. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-restrictions.html

Comment: so if we want to use an aggregate function in a place other then group by clause, we have to place it between semicolons?

Comment: @Avidos - I couldn't find that restriction in the referenced article, only restriction on correlated substitutes in the FROM clause in a view..."Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries. They are materialized in whole (evaluated to produce a result set) before evaluating the outer query, so they cannot be evaluated per row of the outer query."

Comment: Try running it. I've tried it then got this: Error Code: 1349. View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: @Avidos, if you have a MySQL question perhaps you should submit it separately. OP's question is Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this with window (analytic) functions:

```
CREATE VIEW vq1 AS
SELECT productid, productname, unitprice FROM (
    SELECT productid, productname, unitprice, AVG(unitprice) OVER () AS avg_unitprice
      FROM products
) WHERE unitprice > avg_unitprice
  WITH READ ONLY;
```